# Java program to find 'Lucky' numbers from 0 to n using Lists

Tags: java

I have to write a program that finds all the lucky numbers from 0 to any number n.
Here's what a lucky number is:

Consider the sequence of natural numbers.
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ………………………………….
Removing every second number produces the sequence
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23 ………………………….
Removing every third number produces the sequence
1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19, 21, 25 ………………………….

This process continues indefinitely by removing the fourth, fifth…and so on, till after a fixed number of steps, certain natural numbers remain indefinitely. These are known as Lucky Numbers.

I decided to try using ArrayList for this. But I can't seem to figure this small bit out. I've been trying for days now.
Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
class luckyy
{
public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter n: ");

    int i, n, index;
    n = scan.nextInt();     
    ArrayList <Integer> ele = new ArrayList <Integer> (n);
    //storing in a list
    for(i = 1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        ele.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(ele);
    int count = 2;
    index = 1;
    System.out.println("Size: "+ele.size());
    while(count<ele.size())
    {
        for(i = 0;i<ele.size();i++)
        {
            int chk = ele.get(i);
            if(chk%count == 0)
            {
                ele.remove(i);
            }                
        }
        count++;           
    }
    System.out.print(ele);        
}
}
```

This gives the output:
`[1, 5, 7]`
When the desired output is:
`[1, 3, 7]`

So, sorry if this code is so bad that it's offensive haha...
But I would really appreciate any help. I am just starting out as a programmer, and have a lot to learn, and would love any advice. Thanks to anyone who tries to help me!

Comment: Already there is one answer for this in: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37019/optimising-lucky-number-program

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for linking the answer. I appreciate that! :-) However, it doesn't really teach me that much... I get the array code, but I want to understand lists and arraylists better, so I would also appreciate any inputs you have on how they could be used here.

Comment: Actually you checked the linked question.Please check the answer also.There List is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it seems to me that your assumption of the expected output is not correct. According to the task you described, the out should be something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25] // every 2nd number removed
[1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19, 21, 25] // every 3rd number removed
[1, 3, 7, 13, 15, 19, 25] // every 4th number removed
[1, 3, 7, 13, 19, 25] // every 5th number removed
[1, 3, 7, 13, 19] // 6th number removed = final output
```

Beside that, I see two mistakes.

1. You want to remove "every n-th number", so you don't want to test the values, but their position/index in the list.
2. Whenever you remove an element from an ArrayList, the index of the following elements and the size of the list is reduced by 1. Means if you  start with removing the "2", the next number to remove will be the "5", not the "4" as desired (assuming you are testing the index, not the value). One solution for that would be to test the indexes starting at the end of the list. In that case it wouldn't matter that higher indexes change after removing elements, because you already passed them.

**Edit**

Answer edited in regard to request of @Kedar Mhaswade to provide some code in order to test how removing elements from the end of the list perfoms.

This is my first approach:

```
  List<Integer> removeBackward(List<Integer> numbers) {
    int count, sPos;
    count = 2;
    while(count<=numbers.size())
    {
      for(sPos = numbers.size(); sPos >= numbers.size()-count; sPos--)
      {
        if(0 == sPos%count) {
          break;
        }
      }
      for(int pos = sPos; pos > 0; pos=pos-count)
      {
        numbers.remove(pos-1);
      }
      count++;           
    } 
    return numbers;
  }
```

I did some tests (see below) with the result that it performs quite well for small sets of numbers (< 12000). On larger sets the second approach of @Kedar Mhaswade (maintaining an extra list for the elements to retain) outperforms this approach.

Therefore I tried a second approach:

The idea was, that there is no need to maintain a second list for retained elements when at first step half of the elements will be removed and the number of elements to retain decreases step by step. 
So I simply moved the elements to retain to the end of the same list and maintain additional pointers in order to know the range of the retained elements. At the end of the process the final result only needs to be extracted from the end of the list.

```
List<Integer> retainedAtEnd(List<Integer> numbers) {
  int removeX, baseQty, retainedQty, basePos, retainedPos;
  removeX = 1;
  baseQty = numbers.size();
  while(removeX <= baseQty)
  {
    removeX++;
    basePos = numbers.size();
    retainedPos = basePos;
    retainedQty = 0;
    for(int checkPos = baseQty; checkPos >= 1; checkPos--)
    {
      if(0 != checkPos%removeX) 
      {
        basePos = numbers.size()-baseQty+checkPos;
        numbers.set(retainedPos-1, numbers.get(basePos-1));
        retainedPos--;
        retainedQty++;
      }
    }
    baseQty = retainedQty;
  }
  return numbers.subList(numbers.size()-baseQty, numbers.size());
  // return new ArrayList(numbers.subList(numbers.size()-baseQty, numbers.size()));
}
```

According to my test unforunately this approach doesn't perform to good on small sets (<12000). It can not compete with the first or @Kedar Mhaswade's second approach, but on larger sets, it outperforms both.

Here is how I tested:

```
    public void test() {
      int n = 1000;     
      long start;
      System.out.println("Testing with " + n + " numbers ..."); 

      System.out.println("Test removing elements backwards:");
      List<Integer> numbers1 = Stream.iterate(1, k -> k + 1).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
      start = System.nanoTime();    
      List<Integer> out1 = this.removeBackward(numbers1);
      System.out.println("Time taken:" + (System.nanoTime() - start));
  //    System.out.println(out1);

      System.out.println("Test maintaining extra list for retained elements:");
      List<Integer> numbers2 = Stream.iterate(1, k -> k + 1).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
      start = System.nanoTime();    
      List<Integer> out2 = this.extraRetainedList(numbers2);
      System.out.println("Time taken:" + (System.nanoTime() - start));
  //    System.out.println(out2);

      System.out.println("Test collecting retained elements at end of list:");
      List<Integer> numbers3 = Stream.iterate(1, k -> k + 1).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
      start = System.nanoTime();    
      List<Integer> out3 = this.retainedAtEnd(numbers3);
      System.out.println("Time taken:" + (System.nanoTime() - start));
  //    System.out.println(out3);

      System.out.println("Test maintaining extra list for elements to remove:");
      List<Integer> numbers4 = Stream.iterate(1, k -> k + 1).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
      start = System.nanoTime();    
      List<Integer> out4 = this.extraDeletedList(numbers4);
      System.out.println("Time taken:" + (System.nanoTime() - start));
  //    System.out.println(out4);
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for explaining where I went wrong. I didn't really see the flaw in my logic until you pointed it out. Makes a lot more sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem! I went about it in a slightly different fashion and used another list to store the *deleted elements*. This is required because of the data structure that I chose. Since I wanted to use integers only and I was using an `ArrayList`, every time I remove an element, the list gets immediately adjusted. What we really need to do is *mark* the element for deletion. There are more than one way to do this, but I chose to maintain another list of deleted elements (since all the elements are unique, it is fine to use this idea).

Here is my first attempt then:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/** <p>
 *      Find the lucky numbers amongst natural numbers from 1 to n.
 *      Here's how you find <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673769/java-program-to-find-lucky-numbers-from-0-to-n-using-lists">Lucky numbers</a>.
 * </p>
 * Created by kmhaswade on 2/27/16.
 */
public class Lucky {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printLucky1(Integer.valueOf(args[0]));
    }
    private static void printLucky1(int n) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Stream.iterate(1, k -> k + 1).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(numbers);
        int delIndex = 1; // index of the element to be removed, we start with 2nd element
        while (delIndex < numbers.size()) {
            List<Integer> deleted = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = delIndex; i < numbers.size(); i += (delIndex + 1)) {
                deleted.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
            numbers.removeAll(deleted); // expensive operation!
            System.out.println(numbers);
            delIndex += 1;
        }
        System.out.println("number of lucky numbers:" + numbers.size());
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

This works! But for really long lists, this is very slow, because of the expensive operation: `numbers.removeAll(deleted)` -- we are removing bunch of elements from an `ArrayList` that has to move all affected elements on *every* deletion!

For instance, with the first 100_000 natural numbers, it takes about 10 seconds on my computer. Clearly, I looked for an alternative. What if we devise another list and collect the elements that we want to *retain*, and then in the next iteration, this list of retained elements becomes our list to operate on? It looked like that will work better because there is no deletion of elements involved. You will still need to have another `ArrayList` to *collect* the elements. In analysis terms, this is an `O(n)` additional space (or `c.n` where `c ~ 0.5`).

Here's my second attempt then:

```
private static void printLucky2(int n) {
    List<Integer> numbers = Stream.iterate(1, k -> k + 1).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(numbers);
    int delIndex = 1; // index of the element to be removed, we start with 2nd element
    while (delIndex < numbers.size()) {
        List<Integer> retained = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i += 1)
            if ((i+1) % (delIndex + 1) != 0)
                retained.add(numbers.get(i));
        numbers = retained;
        System.out.println(numbers);
        delIndex += 1;
    }
    System.out.println("number of lucky numbers:" + numbers.size());
    System.out.println(numbers);
}
```

There may be more improvements possible because for really large inputs the time taken by this algorithm may still be unacceptable (will work on that improvement). But I already see two orders of magnitude improvement!

Here's the [complete code](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/bf32ba00f1b625312e77). I made sure that both the methods return lists that are same (`list1.equals(list2)` returns `true`) and here is the output on my computer (with first 100_000 numbers):

```
[1, 3, 7, ...]
number of lucky numbers: 357
time taken: 6297
number of lucky numbers: 357
[1, 3, ...]
time taken: 57
```

Comment: I used Java 8 only for the initialization of arrays. You can change it to a basic for loop.

Comment: Didn't test it, but I suppose it is much faster to simply remove  the elements from the one ArrayList starting at the end of the list and moving backwards. No need to maintain a 2nd list and no need for expensive copy or deleteAll operations.

Comment: @Awita Hmm, can you write a program just to verify?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much, this explains what I was doing wrong really well. I really, really appreciate it. I hope you know you have helped me a LOT!

Comment: @Kedar Mhaswade please see my edited answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone still interested, I found another way to do this.
It isn't revolutionary or anything, and it uses a lot of the stuff the people on this thread told me, but it sort of summarizes all the advice I guess.
I felt it only fair to post my answer.
So, it involves iterating through every element, storing all the elements you need to remove in each round of counting, and then using the removeAll function to remove them before the count increases. 
Here's the complete code for anyone interested. Any comments would also be welcome.

```
import java.util.*;
class luckyy
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {        
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter n: ");       
    int i, n, index;
    n = scan.nextInt();     
    ArrayList <Integer> ele = new ArrayList <Integer> (n);
    ArrayList <Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList <Integer> (n);
    //storing in a list
    for(i = 1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        ele.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(ele);
    int count = 2;     
    System.out.println("Size: "+ele.size());
    while(count<=ele.size())
    {

        for(i = 0;i<ele.size();i++)
        {
            if((i+1)%count == 0)
            {                    
                toRemove.add(ele.get(i));
            }                
        }
        ele.removeAll(toRemove);
        toRemove.clear();
        count++;
    }
     System.out.println(ele);
}
}
```

There it is! It works, and boy am I glad! If anyone has any further advice, or anything else for me to learn or checkout, you are totally welcome to comment.
Thanks again everyone!

Comment: unfortunately you choosed the worst performing approach. I did some tests that showed maintaining an extra list for deleted elements and to remove those afterwards is much slower than maintainting a list for the elemtns to retain or to remove the elements backwards from the end of the list (please see my updated answer).